# Cakephp left outer join from query builder is not giving correct sql format

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I want to make sql query like this. Which is working fine. but if I am trying with using cakephp query builder I could not find any path. I am also posting what I have done in cakephp query builder. Please check...

```php
$query = '
    select
        schemes.name,
        most_recent_export_product.itc_hs_code,
        sum(epinvoicevalueusd) from oc
    join (
        select
            oc_id, itc_hs_code
        from
            e_products
        where
            itc_hs_code is not null
        group
            by oc_id
        order
            by oc_id, created desc
    )
        as most_recent_export_product
        on oc.id = most_recent_export_product.oc_id
    join
        schemes on schemes.id = oc.scheme_id
    where
        application_status_id = 8 AND
        certificate_issue_date >= 2022-09-28
    group by
        scheme_id, most_recent_export_product.itc_hs_code
    order by
        scheme_id, most_recent_export_product.itc_hs_code';

$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$ocData = $connection->execute($query)->fetchAll('assoc');
```

In cake php I am using query builder to do the same like

```php
$exdata = $this->EProducts
    ->find()
    ->select(['oc_id', 'itc_hs_code'])
    ->group('oc_id')
    ->order(['created' => 'DESC']);

$ocData = $this->oc
    ->find()
    ->select([
        'scheme_name' => 'Schemes.name',
        'itc_hs_code' => 'ExportProducts.itc_hs_code',
        'epinvoicevalueusd' => 'sum(oc.epinvoicevalueusd)'
    ])
    ->join([
       'exp' => [
           'type' => 'LEFT',
           'conditions' => 'exp.oc_id = oc.id',
           'group' => 'exp.oc_id'
        ]
    ])
    ->contain('Schemes')
    ->where([
        'application_status_id' => 8,
        'certificate_issue_date >=' => '2022-09-28'
    ])
    ->group(['scheme_id'])
    ->order(['scheme_id']);
```

I dont how to make it with using query builder in cakephp. Please help anyone. :)

Comment: Add sample data and expected result please.